# Trying to comprehend a function that has two inputs for parameters in JS (as in functionX(param1)(param2))

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, this

I'm pretty baffled by this question that I came across for my interview prep. It wants me to be able to write a function called multiply that takes in parameters in this haphazard way:

```
multiply(5)(6);
```

I tried to write a callback and then refer to this in the return statement, but it was not kosher.

```
function multiply(function(value){
return this * value;
});
}
```

Does this problem require recursion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call your function in this `multiply(5)(6);` way,

Then you must be searching for ***function currying***. And that can be accomplished by,

```
function multiply(a){
 return function(b){
   return b * a;
 }
} 

//your way
console.log(multiply(2)(2)) //4

//The standard way
var multiplyBy5 = multiply(5);
var res = multiplyBy5(3); 
console.log(res); // 15;

var multiplyBy10 = multiply(10);
var res = multiplyBy5(3);
console.log(res); // 30;
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense

Comment: @Jon Glad to help! :) Try to press the tick mark present inside this answer, if you feel that this answer has helped you. And this is not a compulsion. :)